# Magento 2: Can not see Stock/Qty box in product level in admin panel

Tags: magento2

is any idea about why i can not see the qty box in product admin page, There is no option to add any qty box.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check, is MSI is configured? If yes then there will be another section to add qty for product.

Comment: thanks @RahulBarot but its solved now. quantity_and_stock_status attribute missing somehow that's the reason it was not there.